# Sitecore, why is so difficult?

Tags: html, content-management-system, sitecore

I am new to sitecore and my company has been using external company to manage their sitecore, which I totally understand, since it involved so much work on the development.

As a designer myself, I found extermely difficult to create a custom page unless I use what's already available. I could use simple page to insert my html codes but again, it's just way too long. In regular case, when you build a html site, you could simply create pages in dreamweaver and view it on your local computer.

I have tried to make a custom page with the presentation control, but each time I called a sub-rendering. the page is just a BLANK.

> **so my 1st question will be, What's the procedure to create a custom page? **

I know sitecore suppose to be powerful and there is many api, I really would like to find out why I found it's so difficult......

my background is, designer base with knowledge of html, css, and php. I am not a developer that's for sure. :)

Thanks for taking time read my blah blah..:)

Comment: This is a great site for learning Sitecore: http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net
It appears you are in more of a content editor role than a developer. Based on your questions, I suspect that that the company that developed your site has not provided you with adequate training to be able to maintain it.

Comment: It's easy to get frustrated when you are coming from a background of static HTML sites. My only advice would be to memorize all of the various pieces that make up a page in sitecore. Item, Data Template, Fields, Presentation Details, Layout, Renderings, Device, etc. These should all be second nature if you are going to attempt to design in Sitecore.

Comment: _I am new to sitecore and my company has been using external company to manage their sitecore, which I totally understand, since it involved so much work on the development._ - I think you've kind of answered your own question: you hire experts and people with experience for a reason

Answer (score 5):

**1st question will be, What's the procedure to create a custom page?**

To answer your first question, there are some high levels steps you would generally take.

1. Create a page template that includes any fields or metadata you need to render the page
2. Create any layouts, sublayouts, or renderings necessary to render the custom page - this is where having access to a developer normally becomes necessary
3. Assign the renderings and datasources to the instance of your new template (or better yet, assign the renderings to __Standard Values item)
4. Publish everything out

You should reference the [Self-Study to Building a Very Simple Site from Sitecore](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/training%20materials/basic%20site/selfstudyguide-buildingaverysimplewebsite_usletter.pdf)

**2nd question will be, why do we need to call the developer each time when we want to have some feature inputs?**

To answer your second question: To get very far with customizing Sitecore you will need to be a developer or have access to one.  This can be mitigated to some extent depending on how flexible the solution is they developed.  But let's be real - Sitecore is an Enterprise CMS, it's not Wordpress where you can install a theme and a few plugins.

As someone just learning, there are a number of options

- [Training from Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/Support/Training.aspx) - this is probably your best bet
- [Download and play with Launch Sitecore](http://www.launchsitecore.net/) for sample code and examples to build a real website
- Check out the [Sitecore Marketplace](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/) for modules that can get things done for you
- Subscribe to and read [John West's blog](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog.aspx) for inside information of basically every aspect of Sitecore

**3rd question is, why I can access the CSS?**

This question doesn't make sense frankly, so I will assume it was meant to ask "How?" or "Where?"  Without any more information about the site in question, you can normally map the URL to the location on disk.  For example:

`http://www.mysite.com/css/styles.css`

This URL might map to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\website\css\styles.css`

I do highly recommend that any code changes, including CSS, be done through your source control system and only be deployed following your standard release management.

Honestly, I don't believe you are qualified to modify and maintain the Sitecore site given your current training and experience level.  The first step I recommend is getting that Sitecore developer training and any training available from your vendor on the specific implementation.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, Patrick! I believe I didn't get enough training as well. My company is really piss off on the development company and would like to move away from sitecore. After couple days of research, I'm getting confidence on sitecore system, what I need to do is really learn it! :)

Comment: The community on stack overflow is very smart and responsive, they've helped me many times so go ahead and ask as you learn.